# Extjs Alert Box without Header and Buttons

Tags: extjs, messagebox

I need to create a Alert in Extjs plain with a text , but when we use Ext Message Box we get a header with close option and buttons. Please help me to alert the user only with a text message and should fade off after some seconds by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a [toast](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.Toast)! It's available since ExtJS 5.

Use header: false to hide the header. The autoCloseDelay is set in milliseconds, and defaults to 3000.

Example:

```
Ext.toast({html: 'Some alert here.', header: false, autoCloseDelay: 5000});
```

**Edit**: For centering the toast in ExtJS 6 and 5, see this fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ua

Comment: Is it possible to show a toast at the Center of Screen?

Comment: Sure, I'll upgrade my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Quick answer .. Its working fine. Now i need to set a time to make it autoClose. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Don't forget you can use the autoCloseDelay property in the object configuration :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even after setting autoCloseDelay toast doesn't disappear , i am looking into it.

Comment: Mind to share your code? I've run some tests and my toast has closed in all of them.

Comment: Here is my Code Snippet: ` var toast = Ext.widget('toast', {html: 'Some alert here.',autoCloseDelay :1000,hideDuration:500, header: false, afterShow: function() { this.center();} });`

Comment: Yes We are using Ext 6.

Comment: I see... I've tried some testing with my previous example and it turned out to behave differently between Ext 5 and 6. I'll soon update my answer.

Comment: This solution will not work if you show multiple toasts at the same time, they will just stack on top of each other

Answer (score 1):

Instead of centering a toast (since you will need to do more hacking to not break toast like the other answer), why not extend Ext.window.MessageBox and handle it yourself? It does everything you want except it shows a header. Here's a fiddle example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ue

So now all you have to do is use it like:

```
Ux.Msg.alert('Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
```

Comment: I had extended the window as you told and achieved many more results , Thanks a lot!